# Assets file project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net7.0-ios'. visual studio in MAC

Tags: .net, visual-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDVlq.png)

i can create the archive   with visual studio  they can give me the issue i can check all reasons but all answer give in the  windows not in the mac . i want answer  in visual studio mac

anybody have can fix this issue

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.